# which view/widget can support zooming in android?

Tags: android, view, zooming

I think my question is fairly clear, I would like to know if every kind of view can support zoom.
I know that some have built in zoom controls like the `MapView` and the `WebView`, but how about a `LinearLayout` with some `TextView`s and `ImageView`s?

I will edit this post to have a list of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if every kind of
>   view can support zoom

No. The only widgets with built-in zoom that I am aware of are `MapView` and `WebView`.

Comment: mmm. That's what I thought... I will do without it then.
Thanks Mr MM.